# Setting the type of an anonymous function TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have an anonymous function in Express like so:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // ...
});
```

and I want to set the type of the function to `ErrorRequestHandler` (Not the return type!).

I can do it like this:

```
const X: ErrorRequestHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  // ...
}
app.use(X);
```

But is there a syntax to do it inline? Like this:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // ...
} : ErrorRequestHandler); // Note: this doesn't work.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify return type in TypeScript arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270393/specify-return-type-in-typescript-arrow-function)

Comment: No, because it only shows how to set the return type of the function

Comment: I edited my question to distinguish from that question. I want to specify the type of the _function_ itself, not the return type.

Comment: Type inference should be correct and no annotation should be required

Comment: @AluanHaddad  That's what I first thought would happen too, but with Express types are not inferring automatically here.  I assume it's because `app.use` has overlaps with parameter count here, so Typescript can't determine which one you want from parameter count only.

Comment: @Keith that's interesting. Perhaps if you specify the parameter types, that will be sufficient

Comment: @AluanHaddad  Just tried it, unfortunately you then have to put all parameters types in, and then that kind of defeats the whole point of casting it.  Using the extra brackets and cast as ErrorRequestHandler seems to be the most succinct way I can find.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's not type safe.

Comment: @AluanHaddad  No, it's still type safe, as app.use would still throw.

Comment: No, I mean that it allows your function to be written incorrectly but it's a small point. A type assertion is different from a type annotation. Your solution seems workable I just wouldn't opt for it. I would probably declare another signature for `use`  in an augmentation

Comment: @AluanHaddad  Not sure what you mean, could you give an example.

Comment: I know there's a loophole, but I come up with a solid example right now. The parameter types are flowing backward from the assertion correctly. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad  No problem, I currently can't make it fail, but if there is a gotcha it would be great to know, and I could add it as gotcha on my answer.  Hate to think this is a hack ready to fail.  I wonder what express dev's suggest, as the implicit typing is not working for this case.  ps. things like `app.get('/', (req, res) => {})` work fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use some extra brackets to help Typescript out.

eg..

```
app.use(<ErrorRequestHandler>((err, req, res, next) => {
}));
```

You can of course use `as` too, to avoid any JSX confusion.

```
app.use(((err, req, res, next) => {
}) as ErrorRequestHandler);
```

Notice how above the whole function is enclosed inside brackets, this allows Typescript to apply the typecast to the whole function expression.

Code completion on `req`, `res`, & `next` will then work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

typescript anonymous function type

```
lass Foo {
    save(callback: (n: number) => any) : void {
        callback(42);
    }
}
var foo = new Foo();

var strCallback = (result: string) : void => {
    alert(result);
}
var numCallback = (result: number) : void => {
    alert(result.toString());
}

foo.save(strCallback); // not OK
foo.save(numCallback); // OK
```

Comment: I get you, the problem with this though is that I cannot specify the type of `app.use`, that's built into Express