# TypeScript throws error for return function type

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

I'm very new to TypeScript. I am trying to type this mock function and it's throwing in the following error:

> Value of type '() => { doc: { name: string; header: string; body:
> string; category: string; isFunction: boolean; isOperator: undefined;
> supportedExecutionContexts: string[]; }; error: undefined; }' has no
> properties in common with type 'IQuickHelpDocs'. Did you mean to call
> it?ts(2560)
>
> getHelpDocs.ts(27, 49): Did you mean to call this expression?

Code:

```
export const getHelpDocs: IHelpDocs = () => ({
  doc: {
    name: 'demo',
    header: 'demo',
    body: 'Returns the demo value of <code>value</code>',
    category: 'Number',
    isFunction: true,
    isOperator: undefined,
    supportedExecutionContexts: ['calc', 'my'],
  },
  error: undefined,
})
```

**Types.ts**

```
export interface IHelpDocs {
  doc?: IDoc
  error?: IDocsError
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you are assigning a function to an interface.

Comment: thank you for your response @DanielA.White I'm very new to typescript. How can I solve this? I thought I was typing the return value of the function no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify return type in TypeScript arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270393/specify-return-type-in-typescript-arrow-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotation you've currently written says that `getHelpDocs` is of type `IHelpDocs`:

```
export const getHelpDocs: IHelpDocs = ...
```

What you probably wanted to convey instead is that it's a function that takes no arguments and returns `IHelpDocs`:

```
export const getHelpDocs: () => IHelpDocs = ...
```

What may be confusing here is the type annotation. For functions, you can annotate the return type as follows:

```
export function getHelpDocs(): IHelpDocs { ... }
```

For variables, you'll need to annotate the whole shebang, otherwise Typescript won't know to expect a function — it could just as well be that you did want to have just the interface.

Answer (score -2):

You are telling TypeScript `getHelpDocs` should be in the shape of `IHelpDocs`, which it is not. It's a function that returns a `IHelpDocs`.

I would change this to export a `function` directly:

```
export function getHelpDocs(): IHelpDocs {
 return {  
    doc: {
    name: 'abs',
    header: '<code>abs(value)</code>',
    body: 'Returns the absolute value of <code>value</code>',
    category: 'Number',
    isFunction: true,
    isOperator: undefined,
    supportedExecutionContexts: ['calc', 'sql'],
  },
  error: undefined,
  };
}
```

Comment: How can I change this to use implicit return with ES6 const?

Comment: @t there's little need to make it that way  - this is much more clear IMO.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I'd love to know how do i use ES6 with implicit return. Is it possible? (PS: I didn't rate that answer)