# Typescript cast any to type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Related to:

[Specify return type in TypeScript arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270393/specify-return-type-in-typescript-arrow-function)

[Why am I getting an error "Object literal may only specify known properties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816061/why-am-i-getting-an-error-object-literal-may-only-specify-known-properties)

In:

`hooks/Test.tsx`:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

interface GeoLocationData {
    isGeoLocationDataSet: boolean
    lat: string
    lon: string
    errorCode: number,
    errorMsg: string
}

export const Test = (): GeoLocationData => {
    const [geoLocationData, setGeolocationData] = useState<GeoLocationData>({
        isGeoLocationDataSet: false,
        lat: '',
        lon: '',
        errorCode: 0,
        errorMsg: ''
    });

    // stuff here
    return geoLocationData
}
```

`geoLocationData` is not cast to type `GeoLocationData` when used in another component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Test} from './hooks/Test';

function App() {
  const geoLocation = Test
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <body className="App-body">
        <p>
          {geoLocation.isGeoLocationDataSet
            ? JSON.stringify(geoLocation)
            : "No"}
        </p>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

err:

```
Property 'isGeoLocationDataSet' does not exist on type '() => GeoLocationData'.ts(2339)
```

But `isGeoLocationDataSet`does exist as a prop in `GeoLocationData`.

The following `()`:

```
export const Test = (): GeoLocationData => ({
    const [geoLocationData, setGeolocationData] = useState<GeoLocationData>({
        isGeoLocationDataSet: false,
        lat: '',
        lon: '',
        errorCode: 0,
        errorMsg: ''
    });

    // stuff here
    return geoLocationData
})
```

produces:

```
Type '{ const: [GeoLocationData, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GeoLocationData>>]; return: any; }' is not assignable to type 'GeoLocationData'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'const' does not exist in type 'GeoLocationData'.
```

but return is still an.

Comment: you're not calling `Test`, try `Test()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test` is a function, so you need to call it to get the returned value of type `GeoLocationData`:

```
const geoLocation = Test();
```