# How to specify return type for TypeScript anonymous inline arrow function

Tags: typescript, types

There is this question and answer which helps give a concise way to define the shape of a NAMED arrow function, but does not touch on anonymous inline functions:
[Specify return type in TypeScript arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270393/specify-return-type-in-typescript-arrow-function)

I would like to map one object type to another object type using a simple inline anonymous arrow function:

```
type MyType = {
    foo: string
};
type OtherType = {
    bar: string
};

const myTypeArr: MyType[] = [{foo: 'abc'}, {foo: 'qwe'}];

// note the anonymous inline arrow function below
const otherTypeArr: OtherType[] = myTypeArr.map(o => ({bar: o.foo}));
```

The compiler seems to accept this as valid code.  And throws errors if I do something like this:

```
// Error: Property 'baz' does not exist on type 'MyType'.
const otherTypeArr: OtherType[] = myTypeArr.map(o => ({bar: o.baz}));
// Error: Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ baz: string; }' but required in type 'OtherType'
const otherTypeArr: OtherType[] = myTypeArr.map(o => ({baz: o.foo}));
```

But I believe it is inferring the types in the anonymous function.  Is there a way to specify the input types and return types explicitly?

I think I can specify the input type easily like this:

```
const otherTypeArr: OtherType[] = myTypeArr.map((o: MyType) => ({bar: o.foo}));
```

But I still don't see a way to manually specify the return type on the function.  Is the fact that I already specify `OtherType[]` in the variable the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in the [answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40270735/2887218) works here too.  Even anonymous arrow functions allow you to annotate the return type with a colon after the parameter list's closing parenthesis and before the arrow, like this:

```
(o: MyType): OtherType => ({ bar: o.foo })
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- return type annotation
```

And you can verify that this works as desired:

```
const otherTypeArr =
    myTypeArr.map((o: MyType): OtherType => ({ bar: o.foo }));

// const otherTypeArr: OtherType[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQGYHt8AuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMMBfAbg1EigHlgALCCxB1SYcUAEYBDCiXLV6TVhgDG+GuSgBbBEgCCFabG2QA2gF0oqY2jyESAcglildqIwA06G8Sh2AjgHcIF0ZTRWVVdXxefkEIPQoLLBwtWPiAOg0JMAAKbO84WIBKEm4+ASQLAD4obOtJA3w0gnxXQsLFAHoOqBU1YCgostT9Eujyk1MgA)

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for.  But I also like the cleanness of the other answer.  Probably would be overkill to specify both and the other answer lends itself better to chained maps/functions:
`const anotherArr = o.map<SomeType>(a => b).map<OtherType>(b => c).map<AnotherType>(c => d);`

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a generic type argument to `array.map<T>()`, like this:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoDMD2eAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3BgL6OiRQDywAFhOYu1SZsAIwCG5YmSp1GLDBgDGeamSgBbBEgCC5SbC2QA2gF0oqI1nT4iUAORiRiu0wA0VtDeJ2AjgHcIF3cTRgwAejCoADcJSkcAG2hKEigxamo8YDFgCAATJRU1TN5+HT0ARmIuEoEIU3MNQwhdcgA6dTEwAAo8cwA+KC60cX08VpsmAEpJ0IiocghgAFdyaig2aDwcKEUxePjxRQBrXCXqRWBKFShk0khFShxKPJu12ghqPkpFdaRU8loSw+wHWvQk5DEIHanQKqhBxT4tRaACYGpokXpoWAADzVRFIPo9fqDYYSYhjCbTRhAA)

```ts
// variable is annotated
const otherTypeArr1: OtherType[] = myTypeArr.map(o => ({bar: o.foo}));

// return type of callback function is specified in generic type arguent to array.map
const otherTypeArr2 = myTypeArr.map<OtherType>(o => ({bar: o.foo}));
```