# Specify the return type of a TS arrow function as a type refinement

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to specify the return type of an arrow function as being a type refinement?

```
function foo(x: unknown): x is string {
  return typeof x === 'string';
}

// neither of these works
const bar = (x: unknown) => (typeof x === 'string') as x is string;
const baz = (x: unknown) => <x is string>(typeof x === 'string');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify return type in TypeScript arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270393/specify-return-type-in-typescript-arrow-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for a return type of an arrow function is similar to a regular function. After the argument list, you put a colon, and then the return type:

```
const bar = (x: unknown): x is string => typeof x === 'string';
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4wLwwBQA8BcMCuYA1mCAO5gCUeWMAlhDNEnWAOZoB8MUAngA4BTEADMYtVJJgByZqzbSA3AChloSLCgALeXkIlyYNDJ1LldMRkRIM2+ZUowA3spgx1EEABtBAOi8gbLY67L5QIACq-EJIAMIIEIIYDsoAvkA)