# Fixing typescript error in the return type of my function

Tags: typescript

I have this function that returns an array of strings or undefined, typescript correctly infers the return type :

[image]

However if I explicit state that return type in the function I get an error:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check more about adding type for arrow function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270393/specify-return-type-in-typescript-arrow-function)

it should be:

```js
export const getBannerImgsId = (componentSlot: ContentSlot): string[]|undefined => {
 // your codes
}
```

or

```js
export const getBannerImgsId = (componentSlot: ContentSlot): (componentSlot: ContentSlot) => string[]|undefined => {
 // your codes
}
```

or for the way I'm doing. ( I think it would be better for teamwork )

```js
type BannerFunction = (componentSlot: ContentSlot) => string[]|undefined;

export const getBannerImgsId = (componentSlot: ContentSlot): BannerFunction  => {
 // your codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typing the return value of an arrow function should be done `after` the parentheses, like this:

```
    const myFunction = (numbers: number[] | undefined): number[] | undefined => {
  return numbers?.filter(num => num !== 1)
}
```

You can read more about Function Types in the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).